# The [featured] tag is not a mod-only tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

> [image: screenshot]

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) is supposed to be mod-only, but it's not!

To prove it, I've attached the tag to this very question. It doesn't seem to be taking effect (making this question show up in the sidebar) though.

Comment: Does "featured" have the same context on Meta SE as it does on MSO?  I'd argue that Meta SE would need it more than here.

Comment: ... it doesn't do anything, apparently.

Comment: @Makoto I wasn't sure, but it does appear to be defined on [other](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) [metas](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/featured).

Comment: featured tags on other sites often take as many as 10 minutes or so to take effect.

Comment: It appears that you've officially made this a featured post!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure how this happened really, but we fixed it.  It's a one-of-a-kind operation to move sites like this...not super surprising there will be a few cleanup items here and there.  And now, bedtime!